# Error to update app from Google Play but not to uninstall and reinstall

Tags: android, google-play, updates, uninstallation

I created an app and I've tested on a real device and it works fine. I've published on Google Play and I have uploaded 3 more versions.

But in the last version I published, the people try to update the app have the error when to try to enter the app when the app is downloaded correctly:

**Has stopped application AppName**. The error is how this in Spanish: [Error link](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-_Lc4wAs-psg/USfuandXSRI/AAAAAAAAAQY/w14IEpZvN9U/s1600/mensajeerror.png)

But if you uninstall the app and your back to install of Google Play, it works fine.

Help me please.

Comment: find what the error is, there is no possible way we can tell you the problem without that

Comment: The problem is that I have not errors. The error is to update the app in Google Play. The if you uninstall and reinstall, the app works

Comment: The error will still generate log entries. You could publish a private alpha or beta release and install, update and look at your logcat during and after.

Comment: you can report the error and have it viewable in your developer console

Comment: Have you changed the key signature?  Have you changed the package name?  Is there anything innately different in how you formatted your app than before?

Comment: @tyczj how I do the report error?

Comment: @AndrewSchuster yes, the api key and package name in src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an application, once you upload it to the Google Play Store, it is uniquely identified by the package name you gave it.  [I've found an article that details what can't change once an app is uploaded](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html).

From that post:

> Once you publish your application under its manifest package name,
>   this is the unique identity of the application forever more. **Switching
>   to a different name results in an entirely new application, one that
>   can’t be installed as an update to the existing application.**

So that explains why people can't simply update the application.  It's because to the Android operating system it is *an entirely different application*.  Even if all the code is the same, that small change differentiates it.

If you read slightly further:

> Just as important as the manifest package name is the certificate that
>   application is signed with. The signing certificate represents the
>   author of the application. **If you change the certificate an
>   application is signed with, it is now a different application because
>   it comes from a different author.** This different application can’t be
>   uploaded to Market as an update to the original application, nor can
>   it be installed onto a device as an update.

And finally:

> If the signing certificate changes, trying to install the new
>   application on to the device will fail until the old version is
>   uninstalled.

So, in summary, you changed things you shouldn't have.  Keep your package name the same and sign with the same key every time you upload an app to the store.

Comment: But I have not changed the package name in Manifest. I have changed the package names in src folder. And the Api key.

Comment: What do you mean by API key?

Comment: meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="..."/>

Comment: Based on the information you've given, this is the best guess I could give.  I hope you find the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Every time I publish the app you need to change the api key?

Comment: No, the API key for Google Maps should have nothing to do with your app not updating correctly.  It is probably tied somehow to the change in package name, even if you didn't change it in your manifest.